# Localhost returns 404.3 when fetching json through ajax (Windows 8.1)

Tags: ajax, json, iis, windows-8.1, webmatrix

So I have been getting the infamous 404.3 error when trying to use AXAJ to access a .json file launching the site (or more of a test app hehe) through WebMatrix on localhost.

Yes, I am aware of the IIS configuration. I am on Windows 8.1(x64), so I had to even turn on MIME types functionality separately. I configured a MIME type for `.json` with `application/javascript`. Then I went and added a handler to `*.json`, pointed it to `C:\WINDOWS\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll`. I set the verbs to GET and POST (those are what I use in my ajax function). I also tried unchecking the "Invoke the handler only if request is mapped to..." to no avail.

I am using one function to send data to PHP file which writes it to the JSON file and then another to fetch data from the JSON file directly. Writing through PHP works. Fetching doesn't. I am completely at a loss, does anyone have any ideas? The code I am using to fetch the data is your bog-standard ajax:

```
function getDate(path, callback) {
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
            if (callback) callback(data);
        }
     }
  };
  httpRequest.open('GET', path);
  httpRequest.send(); 
}
```

When I host this on my server space, it works totally fine. But I want to get it to work locally for testing purposes as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lengths I go to, to clean up my profile...

When you require a JSON format, or any file for that matter you have to specify in your request what data type you need, IIS will not make any assumptions. So

```
xhr.setRequestProperty('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

is something one must not forget. I set also the `X-Requested-With` header. Note that to reproduce this issue I used IIS that is installed on Windows 10 Pro, so not exactly the same system (3 years later - holy crap!).

Answer (score 0):

If writing to the file works but fetching doesn't work. Then you should check for the link of the file.

The error **404** as the name refers to, is an error for the file name. There isn't any other sort of error, even the Ajax request is working fine and giving the error 404 (file not found). So the only thing that you can do is, to make sure that while fetching the data, you use the correct link.

Here can be a help, when you send the Request through Ajax, there is a Network tab in your Browser's console. Open it, and look for the request. It would in red color denoting an error and click it. You'll see that the link you're providing isn't valid.

Look for the errors in the File Link then and update it.

Comment: File link is correct. It's not just 404, it's 404.3, meaning MIME type restriction. This means the file is seen, but not recognized. Even though I configured the IIS to recognize .JSON files.